# How to iterate through two dictionary objects (both key,value) using two nested for loops in python?

Tags: python

```
def multpoly(d1,d2):
    d3=[]
    d1=dict(d1)
    d2=dict(d2)
    for key,value in list(d1.items()):
        for key2,value2 in list(d2.items()):
            #print(key,value)
            print(key2,value2)
        print(key,value)


d1={1:1,-1:0}
d2={1:2,1:1,1:0}
```

wrong output:

```
1 0
1 1
1 0
-1 0
```

Expected:

```
1 2
1,1
1,0
1,1
-1,0
```

I am getting wrong output with this code?
Can anyone help me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Try just this instead of your whole code: `d2={1:2,1:1,1:0}; print(d2)`. Then read the [docs on dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do here... are you just trying to print out the two dictionaries?

Comment: @Sayse I am trying to make a code to multiply to polynomial. def multpoly(d1,d2):
    d3=[]
    d1=dict(d1)
    d2=dict(d2)
    for key,value in list(d1.items()):
        for key2,value2 in list(d2.items()):
            r1=key*key2
            v1=value+value2
            print(r1,v1)

Comment: @zvone this is not the full code,I am trying to multilpy two polynomial def multpoly(d1,d2):
    d3=[]
    d1=dict(d1)
    d2=dict(d2)
    for key,value in list(d1.items()):
        for key2,value2 in list(d2.items()):
            r1=key*key2
            v1=value+value2
            print(r1,v1)

Comment: Whether that is the full code or not is not relevant. The error is in line `d2={1:2,1:1,1:0}`. If you `print(d2)`, you will see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong with your code:  dicts can only contain each key once.

If you specify

```
d1={1:1,-1:0}
d2={1:2,1:1,1:0}
```

You get `dict` `d1` with contains keys `1` and `-1` with its values and you get `dict` `d2` wich contains only `1` as key (with value of 0 as this one was specified last).

Test:

```
d1={1:1,-1:0}
d2={1:2,1:1,1:0}

print(d1)  # {1: 1, -1: 0}

print(d2)  # {1: 0} - both of 1:2,1:1 were overwritten by the last key 1:0 spec
```

Comment: def multpoly(d1,d2):
    d3=[]
    d1=dict(d1)
    d2=dict(d2)
    for key,value in list(d1.items()):
        for key2,value2 in list(d2.items()):
            r1=key*key2
            v1=value+value2
            print(r1,v1) I am using this code to multiply two polynomial. Input is in this form multpoly([(1,1),(-1,0)],[(1,2),(1,1),(1,0)]) do i need to swap key and value after coverting my input list to dictinory(i dont know how to do that) or is there any other method in python?

Comment: @mohittyagi Seems you still got questions.Please remove the green tick while this is so.